# FOSUserBundle modified profile edit page

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have updated my registration form, added a few fields. Registration works properly, nowever when i go to Profile/edit page, i do not see the new fields. Even I manually try to add

```
 {{ form_widget(form.country) }}
```

it does not work, can not find country. Which file i need to update to be able to update the profile edit page?

Entity\User

```
protected $position;

/**
 * Set position
 *
 * @param string $position
 * @return User
 */
public function setPosition($position)
{
    $this->position = $position;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get position
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPosition()
{
    return $this->position;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `ProfileFormType` class following something similar to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html). Also, for validation, FOSUserBundle uses 2 validation groups: Registration and Profile. You need to add the Profile validation group to your property.

Comment: The link is dead.